# Webforms: submitdisabledcontrols=true keeps some controls disabled

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, disabled-control

So, I am working on this problem since a bit and I cannot find any way through. I tried some things but none worked so far...

## Problem:

In simple, the problem is that when we play with the controls of a form which has *submitdisabledcontrols="true"*, there seem to be some WebForms auto-generated javascript that refreshes (after some time) the UI and keeps some fields disabled even though the user just enabled them.

This happens with Webforms (.NET 4.5.2, but it seems to be true on previous version of .NET).

Chrome and Firefox are fine.

## Concretely:

Here is exactly the form I have in a master page (so all the pages will use it)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" submitdisabledcontrols="true">
<div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is an extract of what we have in one of the pages (I cleaned up a bit for you, so you're not annoyed with the old style CSS tab formatting):

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RB_foo" onclick="setEnabled();" runat="server" EnableViewState="False" GroupName="Action"></asp:RadioButton>
<asp:RadioButton ID="RB_bar" onclick="setEnabled();" runat="server" CssClass="control_checkbox" EnableViewState="False" GroupName="Action"></asp:RadioButton>
<asp:RadioButton ID="RB_parentopt" onclick="setEnabled();" runat="server" CssClass="control_checkbox" EnableViewState="False" GroupName="Action"></asp:RadioButton>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkboxwithchildren" runat="server" CssClass="control_checkbox" onclick="setEnabled();" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RB_opt1" onclick="setEnabled();" runat="server" CssClass="control_checkbox" EnableViewState="False" GroupName="Deliver"></asp:RadioButton>
        <asp:RadioButton ID="RB_opt2" onclick="setEnabled();" runat="server" CssClass="control_checkbox" EnableViewState="False" GroupName="Deliver"></asp:RadioButton>
```

setEnabled(); is controlling the state of each input according to who is enabled or not following the rule that a child is enable if and only if the parent is enabled. This is not a problem as, when we click on "parentopt", we got from [this state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg8XH.png) to [this state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBzkL.png).

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxIup.png) then appears after a few seconds (but not everytime) and I can see that the checkboxes are flickering like if something was updating it on regular bases.

## Investigations:

1- I could find out that changing to submitdisabledcontrols="false" get rid of it, but I still need the disabled controls when submitting...

2- Looking a bit deeper in what ASP is creating me. I could see that it is creating a form inside an iframe which looks like this :

```
<form id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" action="./ASKeywordChecking.aspx" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

This "WebForm_OnSubmit()" calls a "WebForm_ReEnableControls()" which plays with the disabled properties of the controls internally and I don't seem to have control over this (generated automatically).

And that's pretty much as far as I could go...

Does anyone ever experienced this ? Do you have any ideas or need any more input one what I have on my side ?